# Use xQuery to extract attribute values that also exist in SQL variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

XML structure:

```xml
<ns0:message xmlns:ns0='xxx:testing'>
  <ns0:field name='AAA'>...</ns0:field>
  <ns0:field name='BBB'>...</ns0:field>
  <ns0:field name='VVV'>...</ns0:field>
  <ns0:field name='CAR'>...</ns0:field>
</ns0:message>
```

I have SQL that will extract the values of the attributes titled `name`:

```sql
SELECT
  ( (SELECT ',' + CHAR(13) + P.N.value('@name', 'varchar(max)')
       FROM myTable.message_xml.nodes('declare namespace ns0="xxx:testing";
                                       ns0:message/ns0:field[ @name = "AAA" or
                                                              @name = "BBB"]') P(N)
        FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('substring(text()[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)')) as ATTRIBUTE_VALUES
```

This returns a column that looks like:

```
ATTRIBUTE_VALUES
---------------
AAA,
BBB
```

My problem is that the list of potential attribute values is quite large.
Instead of repeating `@name = "AAA"` in my query for every attribute value I want to check for, I was hoping I could declare it as a variable like:

```sql
DECLARE @ATTRIBUTES VarChar(Max)
SET @ATTRIBUTES = '(AAA,BBB,CAR,XYZ)'
```

And then just stick the variable in the sql like:

```sql
[@name = sql:variable("@ATTRIBUTES")]
```

but this is not working for any combination of parens,commas,etc I use to build the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contains` function.
Declare a variable like so:

```
DECLARE @ATTRIBUTES VarChar(Max) = '|AAA|BBB|CAR|XYZ|';
```

And in you query instead of `@name = "AAA"` use:

```
contains(sql:variable("@ATTRIBUTES"), concat("|", @name, "|"))
```